# WordPress enqueued script loading twice

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, load, version

I created a highly customized WordPress theme using Timber and ACF Pro and load time has become an issue.  One of the bugs is that a Javascript file is being loaded twice, once with a version number and once without.  I've used `wp_enqueue_script` to load it, so this shouldn't be happening.  What should I look into to fix this?  What other information should I provide?

**EDIT 1**

I load my scripts in an interesting way because I am using RequireJS and have a development mode where the files are loaded individually and one where a concatenated and minified file is loaded; plus, different routes require different Javascripts, which is done to shorten load times on less complex pages:

```
function loadRequireJS() {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        global $post;
        $devMode = false;
        $post_slug=$post->post_name;
        $app_base = $devMode ? $this->theme->uri . '/static/scripts' : $this->theme->uri . '/static/build';
        wp_enqueue_script('requirejs', $app_base . '/require.js');

        if(is_home()) {
            // $deps = $devMode ? array( $app_base . '/index.js') : array( $app_base . '/index-min.js');
            $deps = $devMode ? $app_base . '/index.js' : $app_base . '/index-min.js';
        } else {
            switch($post_slug) {
                case 'designs':
                case 'market-finds':
                case 'travel':
                    // $deps = $devMode ? array( $app_base . '/blog.js') : array( $app_base . '/blog-min.js');
                    $deps = $devMode ? $app_base . '/blog.js' : $app_base . '/blog-min.js';
                    break;
                default: // this is the smallest file and can be loaded into 404 page
                    // $deps = $devMode ? array( $app_base . '/travelExcursionsPage.js') : array( $app_base . '/travelExcursionsPage-min.js');
                    $deps = $devMode ? $app_base . '/travelExcursionsPage.js' : $app_base . '/travelExcursionsPage-min.js';
            }
        }

        wp_localize_script( 'requirejs', 'require', array(
        'baseUrl' => $app_base,
        'deps'    => array($deps)
        ));

        wp_enqueue_script('app', $deps, array('requirejs'));
        wp_enqueue_script('xrayquire', $app_base . '/xrayquire.js', array('requirejs'));
    }
```

Then in my web inspector, the files are loaded in the following way:

[image: web inspector file loading]

It seems to load the versioned and non-versioned script at the same time, so it is a bit perplexing to me if this is an issue or not.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you use `wp_enqueue_script`? Also, in your browser's devTools Network logs can you list the full URLs for the scripts?

Comment: @rideron89 I just edited my question to include that information.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not too familiar with RequireJS. But that may be you're problem. It looks like your WordPress is loading `index-min.js`, and then `require.js` is *also* loading `index-min.js`.

Comment: Ahh I see, well you may be correct.  Usually, with RequireJS, you include it and you point it in the direction of your file from the script tag itself.  Maybe the minification process adds that to the script so I don't need to enqueue the index.min.js at all and require will take care of it, but I'll try it and update with the results.

Comment: Interesting. After glancing from the docs, it does indeed look like you don't need to load your `index-min.js` file yourself. [What I saw](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles)